# ruby on rake test:models syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I have update my file for test under `applicationname/test/models/product_test.rb`

with these tests

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
    end

 test "product price must be positive" do
    product = Product.new(title: "My Book Title", description: "yyy", image_url: "zzz.jpg") 

    product.price = -1
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
    product.errors[:price]

    product.price = 0 
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
    product.errors[:price]

    product.price = 1
    assert product.valid?

 end

end
```

but when I do `rake test:models`

I get this **error**:

```
SyntaxError: C:/work/applicationname/test/models/product_test.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected '\n' expexting : "="
SyntaxError: C:/work/applicationname/test/models/product_test.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected '\n' expexting : "="
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
assert_equal["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
product.errors[:price]
```

You should have:

```
assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"], product.errors[:price]
```

It appears twice in the code, so be sure to fix both appearances.